# Detect multi-touch gesture of touch pad in UWP apps

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

A simple case:

> Use pinch and pan gesture on a touch pad to zoom an image in a `ScrollViewer`

Note that this is a build-in gesture when you use a touch screen. However, when you do this on your touch pad, nothing is going to happened.

I have looked up official [documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn456353.aspx) but the topic articles involved just talks about the build-in gestures which is not open to developers.

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187313.aspx Gestures on the touchpad should work assuming your laptop's touchpad supports them.

Comment: The article talks about the usage of build-in gestures. I want to detect them and via my `code` and do other effects.

Comment: I believe that touch pad gestures are built-in and driver provided, thus not extensible.

Comment: Actually, when you do "pinch & zoom" on your touchpad, you should see the exact same behavior, assuming you are still using a `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at **Manipulation events** here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/touch-interactions